# Why did I get two Home directories?

Tags: installation, partitioning, ssd, home-directory, drive

Fresh install of 13.10, put "swap" and "/home" on 80G hdd and then "/" on a 32G ssd. Everything works fine **BUT** when I examine the drives they both have a "home" directory with a "mike" (that's me) sub directory.

This seems like a rather silly thing for the Ubuntu installer to do since I made a point of installing /home first, where I wanted it.

My question now is, which is the real /home and how do I insure the "mike" files go only on the hdd as I intended?  Should I delete the /home on the ssd?

EDIT: Thank you responders. I see now that when I did Search->Disks->Devices and looked at each drive I should have also checked "Properties" and then I would have seen the /home folder on the ssd was twice the size of the ssd and therefore it must  represent a link to the /home file on the hdd.

Comment: how did you check? can you add the output of `df -h` editing your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Windows, Ubuntu mounts partitions as folders or sub-folders. When you created `/home` partition, it created a folder `home` under `/` and linked (or mounted) it to the partition in the 80 GB drive.

To verify that your home folder inside the 32GB SSD `/` is the actually the partition in the 80GB HDD, just open the **Home** in **Files** (also known as Nautilus) and right click on any empty space and select **Properties**. You should see more than 32GB of Space in your **Home**. You can also use **Disk Usage Analyzer** program to see how the partitions are being used.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

They both are the "real" /home. If you create a file in your home directory on one it should appear in the other. The reason you see both is because the /home folder on the 80GB HDD is mounted on the root partition as /home